# How to remove parentheses from a compressed (preferably gzipped) text file

Tags: awk, sed, gzip

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914435/awk-sed-how-to-remove-parentheses-in-simple-text-file) discussed how to remove parentheses from simple **uncompressed** text files.

The accepted answer suggested the following:

```
cat in_file | tr -d '()' > out_file
```

To my observation, however, this answer is not able to produce the desired effect on **compressed** text files using **gzip**.

Is there any way to remove parentheses from text files compressed with gzip without uncompressing them?

Comment: No, you can't meaningfully change the contents of a compressed file without decompressing it.  Also, useless use of `cat`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, at best you can do it without writing the decompressed file to disk, but you do need to decompress it in order to edit it.

```
 zcat in_file.gz | tr -d '()' | gzip -c >out_file.gz
```